# Python: Find the text within a table header using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a part of a webpage:
The HTML code:

```
<table class="datatable">
<thead>
<tr>
        <td>Company name</td>
        <td>Country / Territory</td>
        <td>2-letter code</td>
        <td>Accounting code (PAX)</td>
        <td>Airline prefix code</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
            <td>Air France</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>AF</td>
            <td>057</td>
            <td>057</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My code:

```
def AIRLINE(code):
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import string
from importlib import reload

reload(sys)

url = 'https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/?airport.search=%s' %(code)

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup = soup.find("td", data-heading="Company name").text
print(soup)
```

I need to retrive the value "Air France" but unbale to target the Company Name header
I get a syntax error in the output.

Error: `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?`

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: add the error you are getting

Comment: Python presents an extensive [traceback](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/) on errors, and it provides more experienced programmers with *much more* information than just the error. Therefore it is appreciated if you include the full traceback; it will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
soup = soup.find("td", data-heading="Company name").text
```

The key `data-heading` is not a parameter of method `find()`, it is the HTML class you want to filter on. To do that, you need to pass a `dict` as parameter to method `attrs` of `soup.find()`.

Give this a try:

```py
text = soup.find("td", attrs={"data-heading": "Company name"}).text
print(text)
```

Comment: Throws error: " print(soup.find("td", {"data-heading": "Company name"}).text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: You can also just look at `soup.findAll("td")`, this will give you a list of all `td`s, and you can only keep those of interest further on. It seems like the `data-heading` fields are created by some JS script, so in the raw HTML you receive from `requests`,  you don't have them.

Comment: This kind of does what I need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/?airport.search=%s")

df = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]

names = df['Company name']

print(names.values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
['21 Air LLC', '40-Mile Air, Ltd.', '8165343 Canada Inc. dba Air Canada Rouge', '9 Air Co Ltd', '9736140 Canada Inc. t/a Pascan']
```